# Pods library is linked twice with first target, as libPods.a and libPods-<targetname>.a

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I have the project, that contains two targets one for iOS and one for OSX.
Here's how the Podfile looks like.

```
# Pods

xcodeproj 'ipolypus.xcodeproj'

pod 'BlocksKit'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'MKStoreKit'

# Objective C
pod 'libextobjc'
pod 'LinqToObjectiveC'

target :ipolypus, :exclusive => false do
    platform :ios, '5.1.1'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
    pod 'EGOTableViewPullRefresh'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'FlurrySDK'

    # AdMob SDK and AdMob mediation adapter
    pod 'AdMob'
    pod 'AdMobMediationAdapterIAd'    
end

target :ipolypusTests, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
end

target :'ipolypus-osx', :exclusive => false do
    platform :osx
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
end
```

After running `pod install` I can see that two Pods libraries are linked against the first target (`ipolypus`).

`libPods.a` and `libPods-ipolypus.a`

If I try to build the project right away, I will get strange link errors, like missing FlurrySDK symbols.

To fix it, I have to remove `libPods.a` and `libPods-ipolypus.a` from the list of libraries to link with the target, run `pod install` again, then manually remove `libPods.a` for the first target and then it will build and link.

There must be something wrong with the way I make that `Podfile`. I checked related posts, couldn't find similar problem.

**Update**

Here's the link error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IOSAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After I do the steps described above, I will have successful builds until next `pod install` or `pod update`.

I should also mention, that the project had single target for quite a while, then I added OSX target and modified `Podfile` for that, and that's when the problems started.
But I tried to remove `Podfile.lock` and to wipe `Pods` folder, still the problem occurs.

And I had another type of error, where linker failed because the same symbol was already defined, but I don't see that one anymore.

Comment: Can you add the errors you're getting? Also I'd look around about the Flurry thing, I know you're not the first person to have issues there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to the cause of "double-linking" problem.
It's caused by the structure of the `Podfile`, as expected.
Since I wanted to have some common pods available both for OSX and iOS targets, I put them all in the beginning.

```
xcodeproj 'ipolypus.xcodeproj'

pod 'BlocksKit'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'MKStoreKit'

# Objective C
pod 'libextobjc'
pod 'LinqToObjectiveC'
```

These common pods will be in `libPods.a` library, also, CocoaPods can't stand the fact that some pods library is not linked against a target, so it will link `libPods.a` against default project target, in my example it's `ipolypus`.

Then there's `libPods-ipolypus.a` generated for `ipolypus` iOS target. Since this target is not exclusive, things like `FlurrySDK` will be included into both `libPods.a` and `libPods-ipolypus.a`, resulting into duplicated symbols while linking.

After trying to figure out the proper way to use exclusive/non-exclusive target configs, I ended up with separate list of pods for each target. Might be a bit longer than I would want, but does the job as expected.

```
# Pods

xcodeproj 'ipolypus.xcodeproj'

target :ios, :exclusive => true do
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    link_with 'ipolypus'

    # shared
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
    pod 'Reachability'
    pod 'MKStoreKit'
    pod 'LinqToObjectiveC'
    # pod 'EGOTableViewPullRefresh'

    # platform
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'FlurrySDK'

    # AdMob SDK and AdMob mediation adapter
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'AdMobMediationAdapterIAd'
end

target :iosTests, :exclusive => true do
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    link_with 'ipolypusTests'
    pod 'OCMock'
end

target :osx, :exclusive => false do
    platform :osx, '10.7'
    link_with 'ipolypus-osx'

    # shared
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
    pod 'Reachability'
    pod 'LinqToObjectiveC'
end

target :osxTests, :exclusive => true do
    platform :osx, '10.7'
    link_with 'ipolypus-osxTests'
    pod 'OCMock'
end
```